# Show that the set of prime ideals of A has minimal element with respect to inclusion

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to check if there is anything wrong with my proof below:

Let S be the set whose elements are prime ideals of A. Impose the following relation on S. $P_1 \leq P_2$ iff $P_2 \subset P_1$. Let $(J)_{\alpha \in U}$ be a chain then Consider $J_{min} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in U} J_{\alpha}$, then we can prove that $J_{min}$ is an ideal. Moreover it is prime. So every chain has an upper bound so by zorn's lemma maximal element exist and by construction this maximal element is the minimal element with respect to inclusion.

Comment: If I were scoring the proof for a class, I'd say that you need more detail on proving that the intersection of a chain of prime ideals is prime.

Comment: Note that you need to define $P_1 \leq P_2$ iff $P_1 \supset P_2$, not $P_1 \subset P_2$

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos  Yes I did that $P_1 \leq P_2$ then $P_2 \subset P_1$

Comment: @DanielSchepler Those details I did them on my own. I just want to make sure I have the main idea of the problem.